# Drawing a Box Around Face To Existed Photos with Google Face Detection ML Kit

Tags: android, android-canvas, face-detection, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

We implemented Android ML Kit for face detection in Android. It works like charm, detect faces.

**The problem:** We want to draw rectangles around detected faces when multiple faces detected

**What we have done:**

Implemented

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:16.1.5'
```

Created a custom View :

```
class FaceView(val theContext : Context, val bounds : Rect) : View(theContext) {

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        val myPaint = Paint()

        myPaint.color = Color.BLACK
        myPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        myPaint.strokeWidth = 10f

        canvas?.drawRect(bounds, myPaint)
    }
}
```

Tried to draw a rectangle to the bound we got from the face object ML kit created

```
val result = detector.process(image).addOnSuccessListener { faces ->

for (face in faces) {
val bounds = face.boundingBox

val view = FaceView(requireContext(), bounds)
binding.actionRoot.addView(view)

val lp : ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams =
 ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(bounds.width(),bounds.height())

lp.startToStart = binding.actionPhoto.id
lp.topToTop = binding.actionPhoto.id

lp.marginStart = bounds.right
lp.topMargin = bounds.bottom
        
view.layoutParams = lp
}}
```

**Result :**

[image]

How can we draw a rectangle for each face that we produced from URI(not from CameraX) and make them clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--  While ML kit gives Rect of detected Faces. I think Google Developers make it more easier for us and draw rectangle automatically and provide faces as standalone bitmap objects.

For my solution :

I used the example project that @anonymous suggested to draw lines around the face.

- First I got start, end, bottom and top points from provided face rect.
  ( This rect is created from original bitmap, not from the imageview. So the rect points are belong to the original bitmap I was using).
- As Rect points are not belong to ImageView but the bitmap itself, We need to find related rect points on ImageView (or create a scaled bitmap and detect faces on it). We calculated this points as percentages in original Bitmap.
- While we use original points as in the example project to draw lines. We implemented a view with Transparent Background with using calculated points to make face rectangles clickable.

-As the last thing we created bitmaps for each face.

```
    detector.process(theImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
    
           val bounds = face.boundingBox
            val screenWidth = GetScreenWidth().execute()
    
            // val theImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(tempBitmap,0)
    
            val paint = Paint()
            paint.strokeWidth = 1f
            paint.color = Color.RED
            paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    
            val theStartPoint = if(bounds.left < 0) 0 else{ bounds.left}
            val theEndPoint = if(bounds.right > tempBitmap.width) tempBitmap.width else { bounds.right}
            val theTopPoint = if(bounds.top < 0) 0 else { bounds.top }
            val theBottomPoint = if(bounds.bottom > tempBitmap.height) tempBitmap.height else { bounds.bottom }
    
            val faceWidth = theEndPoint - theStartPoint
            val faceHeight = theBottomPoint - theTopPoint
    
            Log.d(Statics.LOG_TAG, "Face width : ${faceWidth} Face Height $faceHeight")
    
            val startPointPercent = theStartPoint.toFloat() / tempBitmap.width.toFloat()
            val topPointPercent = theTopPoint.toFloat() / tempBitmap.height.toFloat()
    
            Log.d(Statics.LOG_TAG, "Face start point percent : ${startPointPercent} Face top percent $topPointPercent")
    
            val faceWidthPercent = faceWidth / tempBitmap.width.toFloat()
            val faceHeightPercent = faceHeight / tempBitmap.height.toFloat()
    
            Log.d(Statics.LOG_TAG, "Face width  percent: ${faceWidthPercent} Face Height Percent $faceHeightPercent")
    
            val faceImage = ConstraintLayout(requireContext())
            faceImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
            binding.actionRoot.addView(faceImage)
    
            val boxWidth = screenWidth.toFloat()*faceWidthPercent
            val boxHeight = screenWidth.toFloat()*faceHeightPercent
    
            Log.d(Statics.LOG_TAG, "Box width : ${boxWidth} Box Height $boxHeight")
    
            val lp : ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams =
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    boxWidth.toInt(),
                    boxHeight.toInt()
                )
    
    
            lp.startToStart = binding.actionPhoto.id
            lp.topToTop = binding.actionPhoto.id
    
            lp.marginStart = (screenWidth * startPointPercent).toInt()
            lp.topMargin = (screenWidth * topPointPercent).toInt()
    
            faceImage.layoutParams = lp
    
            val theFaceBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                tempBitmap,
                theStartPoint,
                theTopPoint,
                faceWidth,
                faceHeight)
    
    
            if (face.trackingId != null) {
                val id = face.trackingId
    
                faceImage.setOnClickListener {
                    
                
                    binding.actionPhoto.setImageBitmap(theFaceBitmap)
                    
                 
                }
            }
}
```

Result :

[image]

[image: Clicked Image]

Comment: What's `tempBitmap`?

Answer (score 1):

you can reference the project here, but it is the java code

https://github.com/kkdroidgit/FaceDetect

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked it and I can draw a rectangle around the face with this method. But I also need to be are clickable (To choose the face to change), And the function provided in the project not covers it. My intention is not to create a drawn bitmap but a view on the image.